# Static Resource not found when usercontrol is created from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dependency-injection

I am working on refactoring an application to use property injection.  This has required me to create the views from the code behind like such.  Originally everything was created in XAML and bindings were set to the view models by static resources.  This gave no control over injecting the service for getting data into the view model.

This is the App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
{
    this.MainWindow = new MainWindow(new MainWindowViewModel(new DbDataService()));
    MainWindow.Show();


}
```

MainWindowViewModel is set as the datacontext.
App.xaml contains this resource for viewing the product type class in a listbox:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type classes:Product}">
```

The MainWindow has a tab for each view.  I have a tab's view created like this in MainWindow's constructor:

```
 ProductsTab.Content = new MainView(mainWindowViewModel);
```

When I do this, I get the following error in the MainView on this line:

```
<dxe:ListBoxEdit  Grid.Column="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" ...etc... />
```

"'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '37' and line position '31'."

What I have tried:
I have tried creating the Tab's view in XAML and setting its data context to the parents, however, I still got this exception.
I have tried changing my static resources to dynamic resources, which causes no error at runtime, but the list box does not display the information correctly.

What I need to know:
How to use static/dynamic resources with decency injection.
If there is a better approach to this problem, such as creating the templates in code and injecting them into the views?

Some of my concerns:
I want to add dependency injection to this application, however, I feel like the approach I'm using not only breaks the resources but breaks the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create and call your `MainWindow` in the `OnStartup` method of your App class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        this.MainWindow = new MainWindow(new MainWindowViewModel(new DbDataService()));
        MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

This should work provided that you define the "DataTemplate" resource in your App.xaml (or in a `ResourceDictionary` that you merge from App.xaml).

Comment: That was such a simple fix!  You're a life saver thank you very much :)